# Git: Merge my branch to our Current Working branch

Tags: git, gitlab

So yeah, I got my first job and had the first task and we were instructed to create our own branch based of of the current working branch, now I have done my task and would like to merge my branch to our teams' current working branch. What is the step by step here? need help from you guys, I've searched for articles but I'd still like to know from you guys as I'm a bit hesitant to mess up.

Comment: You have to ask your team. They probably have a procedure for this, such as submitting a pull request. Find out what it is. This isn't an appropriate Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any branch names, so lets `my_branch` be a branch and `feature` is the current branch. Now you need to make sure you are checkout to `feature` branch. To do this type:

```
git checkout feature
```

Now to merge `my_branch` into `feature` branch type:

```
git merge my_branch
```

This will marge the branches and if there is any conflicts you may need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the company should have a process that you should be following...

Gitlab is easiest:

- Push your branch changes into the branch on the repository,
- run any automated testing
- Create a merge request,
- Read it through yourself and fix what you can
- add some reviewers - especially if this is your first contribution,
- fix the issues,
- complete the request.